# Calculating area of polygon in an intersection

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I used the Intersect tool in ArcMap and want to calculate the area of intersection. The intersection is part of a polygon with smaller polygon embedded in it. [image: polygon intersection is area with smaller polygons imbedded]

How do i calculate the area occupied by these smaller polygons which also form part of the intersection?

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the version of software, the coordinate reference system (projected or geographic), and clarify whether the small polygons are *parts* in a multi-part polygon, or discrete polygons.  A zoomed-in graphic which allows visual differentiation of the polygons would be advisable, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to add a new field to your intersect layer. Then right-click the field and select Calculate Geometry. You will be presented with a dialog box in which you can choose the geometry property you wish to calculate - in your case choose Area.

Since you are computing area you must have the data in a projected coordinate system. Equal Area projected coordinate systems will preserve area (ensuring accurate results for area calculations) and therefore are appropriate for your purpose - though the exact coordinate system to use will depend on the scale (global versus regional) and location of your data.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it did work